Tippecanoe not outputing any progress in the terminal
I am running the following on a geojson file that is 41mbs; it runs and produces an output .pmtiles file, but I am not getting any progress bar or output even after hours.
Am I doing something wrong?
docker run -it --rm -v /tiledata:/data tippecanoe:latest tippecanoe -zg --projection=EPSG:4326 --coalesce-densest-as-needed --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping -o Glasgow_grid.pmtiles -l Glasgow_grid.geojson --force
